# How can I find a function from a scatter plot

Tags: functions, exponential-function, graphing-functions

I have few (x,y) raw data and I created a scatter plot with Excel. I'd like to know the actual function that generated this data. I know that there's no method that can automatically find the function, and I know I can find a polinomal expression to approssimate the function. I don't want either of this.
I'd like to know if someone can help me out finding a function that fit this graphic and this raw data:

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bviZx.png)
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjcNg.png)

As you see the function is always positive and it's decreasing. I'm thinking about something like

$ e^{-x/k} $

But it doesn't fit perfecly.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Things won't fit perfectly. Look up regression.

Comment: Take logs of the $y$ column & do linear regression on $x$ and $\ln y$.

Comment: Yes I know, but I'm 100% sure these values are generated by a script that uses just a single simple function, I need to discover which function is. I don't want to use regression. Think about this as a reverse engineering

Comment: At the very least you'll need to try $Ce^{-x/k}$, since your $y$-intercept is not $1$. You can plug in two data points to try and solve for $k$, and then work back to get $C$.

Comment: Even if you know the right function to use, you would still have to fit a regression to estimate the parameters anyway.

If you just want a curve that goes through all the points, you can just fit a polynomial of degree 8 for your 9 data points.

Comment: @AustinMohr this is what I was doing. I actually have 3 parameters: C,k and a, a is the base, so I tried with e but I was trying with other bases too. But it's a long work and I'm pretty sure there are better ways to do this

Comment: @JirapatSamranvedhya yeah I can easily find the polynomial but I don't need that

Comment: Since you have no other information about potential function and you want to reproduce a perfect fit, a polynomial works as well as any function you could come up with. So why do you not want that?

Comment: Because my objective is to know what function this software is using

Comment: Hmm. That's quite a difficult task indeed! Restricting to probability distributions, there are quite a few that look similar to the plot, some being special cases of others. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions#Supported_on_semi-infinite_intervals.2C_usually_.5B0.2C.E2.88.9E.29](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions#Supported_on_semi-infinite_intervals.2C_usually_.5B0.2C.E2.88.9E.29)

Comment: @JirapatSamranvedhya thank you! I'll give it a try. Meanwhile I set up a script that checks every possibile combination of k,m and a in the function m*a^(-x/k) from -200 to 200 by steps of 0.5. The tolerance was 1e-5 and run for 3 hrs and I got nothing. So maybe that wasn't the right function. I'll have to check in the wikipedia page you linked to me